# iOS: UIDatePicker not showing when tap on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITextField` on my `UITableViewCell` for the user to select a time. I want to display a `UIDatePicker` on press the `UITextField` but my below code is not working. Tapping the textfield still shows me the default keyboard.

**EditQuotaCell.h**

```
@interface EditQuotaCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTimeRange;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *txtTimeStart;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *txtTimeEnd;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDatePicker *timePicker;

@end
```

**EditQuotaCell.m**

```
@implementation EditQuotaCell

@synthesize lblTimeRange;
@synthesize txtTimeStart, txtTimeEnd;

@synthesize timePicker;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        self.timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

        self.timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        [self.timePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
        [self.timePicker setMinuteInterval:30];

        self.txtTimeStart.inputView = self.timePicker;
    }

    return self;
}

......
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved it by moving the setting the `inputView` in `awakeFromNib`.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.txtTimeStart.inputView = self.timePicker;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please set your picker view as input view for your textfield in viewdidload

> txtTimeStart.inputView = timePicker;

Comment: indeed. but because this is a `UITableViewCell` it does not have a `viewDidLoad`. I solved it by putting it into `awakeFromNib`. If you can change your answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: But you can do it in cell for row at index path. You should have the reference for your text field in the cell.

Comment: in my case, the `UIDatePicker` is specified in the `UITableViewCell`, which is separate from the `UITableViewController` file.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try with `viewDidLoad:` method

try to set the `inputView` for your `UITextField` in `viewDidLoad:` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

    self.timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [self.timePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self.timePicker setMinuteInterval:30];

    self.txtTimeStart.inputView = self.timePicker;
}
```